# Yii2 dropDownList Default value

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, default, dropdown

In yii2 I have a dropdownlist:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Körperschaft')->dropDownList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C'])?>
```

How can I set 'Item B' as a default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it!
The solutions is to write in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{


    $model->Körperschaft='b';
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Körperschaft')->dropDownList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C'], ['options'=>['b'=>['Selected'=>true]]])?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put it after the lines that are responsible for saving, otherwise, the value will never change even after the user selects a different value. An example below:

```
    public function actionCreate(){
     //Something you want to do before saving
      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
       //Something you do after saving before redirecting
        return $this->redirect(['your-prefered-page']);
    }
     // Some other lines of code
     $model->Körperschaft='b';
     return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
 }
```

I think this can help.

Answer (score 0):

U can use following  code. Here b will appear as a default

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('modelfield', null, ['1' => 'a', '2' => 'b', '3' => 'c'], [ 'class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Rating', 'options' => [ 2 => ['Selected'=>'selected']] ]); 
            ?>
```